# Accurate models in classical mechanics for simulating combat part 1

Tags: science-based, physics, worldbuilding-resources

In order to evade the [Writers can't do math](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/WritersCannotDoMath) and [Sci-fi Writers have no sense of scale](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/SciFiWritersHaveNoSenseOfScale), I wish to use somewhat accurate models to simulate combat and injuries, that I can use to determine the power of the items and to an extent, their reputation in that world.

## Things it needs to simulate:

- A uniform way of determining the damage (force, pressure) of blunt, edged, and other
  weapons inflicted on the materials.
- *Optional: important modifying factors in the mechanical interaction (angle, etc...)*
- Determining an armor's defensive  and other combat related properties, such as the "hit points" of the armor, weight properties, based on
  thickness, materials used in it, and the area it covers

**What is the most accurate model that exist for simulating this (in the realm of classical physics)? If there's no such model, what models exist that cover one of these, that I could combine together?**

Comment: This kind of modeling seems more useful for creating RPG's (specially videogame ones) than to create a sci-fi story proper. I don't think a realistic model exists for what you want.

Comment: I don't think there is any software that could do that, but wounds have been studied for a while especially for forensics purposes. Thus, the best way to make an idea is to get a "human-like" dummy and practice on it. Another option could be to read [articles](http://jamanetwork.com/journals/jama/article-abstract/371915) about those studies. (Use Scihub)

Comment: So remember that training and experience will probably have a far greater effect than the physics of your melee weapons. That's why spears and maces were preferred battlefield weapons over swords, etc.

Comment: @Konchog Although, we want to determine the damage and the forces acting upon the armor when it gets hit, training experience doesn't really matter this time.

Comment: @RedactedRedacted, I think you may not understand how melee actually works. If all you are wondering is what happens when you hit one material on another, you are just looking at materials science. Being thumped hard often does little damage to the armour but can easily kill the person unlucky enough to be hit.

Comment: @Konchog I'm aware of the fact, that forces can bypass the armor.

Comment: What you seek is impossible in general.  Combat probably has thousands of state variables wound up in hundreds of differential equations.  However, we may be able to come up with an approach that would let you develop a system for your particular use cases. For example, you might be able to come up with a system that predicts that the aristocracy will retain control because the balance between aristocratic weapons and peasant armor gives the aristocracy free reign.  You could create a system where the "best" weapons take training to use well, making them unavailable to peasants.

Comment: If you don't mind the tedious amount of work involved in both tracking it down and the investment in learning and playing the system, the Phoenix Command pen&paper RPG has, by far, the most detailed (and probably accurate?) ballistics and injury system imaginable. Alas, most of the math is hidden in the system, but if you tap into old forums a lot of it has been cracked. Game was designed by some NASA engineers, IIRC (and it shows). Probably available on torrent sites as the game has been out of print for decades, maybe drivethrurpg? Also covers melee combat, vehicles, and futuristic stuff.

Comment: Have you tried *Kerbal Space Program* and [*Universe Sandbox*](http://universesandbox.com)?

Comment: @CortAmmon - Actually, it's worse than that. The important effects of muscle-powered weapons are grossly non-linear, full of threshold effects. Hitting an armored opponent 20 times with a 1-pound hammer will not remotely match hitting him once with a 20-pounder.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast It totally depends on what material you're hitting.

Comment: @RedactedRedacted - Only the details. The principle is always valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [Newton's approximation for impact depth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Impact_depth). The approximation assumes that the impactor is blunt and moving very fast so it isn't very good for melee (or ancient missiles) but it should get you on the right track.

The approximation neglects cohesion in the body. So you will need to account for bone and armour (including clothing/cloth armour, which was worn even under metal armour) separately.

I would approach a first approximation to the problem of sharp weapon penetration as follows (with an emphasis on the injuries rather than the armour, which is more complex):

- In the case of a missile, the speed at impact is fixed and falls due to the effects mentioned below.
- In the case of a melee weapon, force may be applied after impact. Assume for simplicity that we can ignore this, especially since the user likely does not want to over-penetrate the target and get their weapon stuck.
- Determine the speed lost in penetrating armour.
- Estimate the impact depth at remaining velocity using Newton's approximation and average tissue density.
- Determine which bones will be crossed along that path, and reduce the speed at that point based on the energy needed to break the bone. Use the medical literature. (If the weapon ricochets off the bone, the problem can of course be more complex.)
- Recalculate the remaining impact depth after bone impact (if sufficient energy is available to pass through the bone).

Comment: And where can I find informations about the cohesion of a material?

Comment: Perhaps you can start with this lecture: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KXHeVM-bSjQ

Comment: So, it's the shear modulus?

Comment: It's the everything to do with how the material holds together. This includes cutting the different fibres in the body, which is heterogeneous.